# How to find centroid flow length in ArcGIS for using Snyder equation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Flow path from centroid to nearest point on flowaccumulation raster then onto outlet point.

Data required to use snyder method for flood hydrograph

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly elaborate your problem. You can take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open ArcMap and add your elevation raster to the map. Go to the
   Spatial Analyst Tools > Hydrology > Flow Direction. Run the tool,
   using the elevation raster as the input and creating a new raster
   for the output flow direction.
2. Next, go to the Spatial Analyst Tools > Hydrology > Flow
   Accumulation. Use the flow direction raster as the input and create
   a new raster for the output flow accumulation.
3. Use the Raster Calculator to find the centroid of the flow
   accumulation raster.
4. Use the Spatial Analyst Tools > Hydrology > Flow Distance. Use the
   flow direction raster as the input and the centroid as the source
   data.
5. Find the nearest point on flow accumulation raster to the centroid
   point.
6. Use the Spatial Analyst Tools > Hydrology > Flow Direction. Use the
   flow direction raster as the input and the nearest point on flow
   accumulation raster as the destination data.

Now you can measure the length of the flow path from the centroid to the nearest point on the flow accumulation raster to the outlet point using the measure tool in ArcMap.
And for the Snyder method, you need to have the precipitation data for the time period of interest, the drainage area and the channel characteristics such as width, depth and slope. With this information, you can use Snyder's equation to estimate the peak discharge and the hydrograph of the flood event.